# How to find 'old' pages in Confluence?

Tags: search, wiki, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Our team has been using a [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) wiki for several years.  We have a lot of old pages I'd like to archive or delete.  I'm wondering if there is a way to identify pages that have not been modified in over a year.  I don't see any option to accomplish this under the admin tools or search features.

Does anyone know to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't archive pages but you can delete them. However, you are able to archive spaces. Thus, If all your old pages are located in same space/spaces you can achieve those spaces and create your new pages in new space.

For finding old pages, I believe you can grab those from the database by checking the `lastmodifidate` of those content. Atlassian has [this documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-do-i-get-more-statistics-from-confluence-154239308.html) that they do have some sample database queries, I believe you can edit those queries base on your need and grab the old pages.

Once you find the pages, if you want to delete from database, you can use the queries from [this KB](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-remove-a-page-manually-in-the-database-using-sql-commands-385321460.html).

FYI, for rest API at the moment you can only grab the pages base on their title or space key not last modified date.

Answer (score 0):

we recently released a plugin called "Outdated for Confluence" which might accomplish what you are looking for.

Users can mark pages as outdated with an additional button.

A outdated review table macro then lets you keep track and review the outdated pages.

For more info see:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219467/outdated-for-confluence?hosting=server&tab=overview

https://emapps.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAD/overview